# Error code 121 - what does it mean?

Tags: google-app-engine

we have an high-replication web application running on GAE, developed with java. The app
has been running fine until today, when we suddenly see lots of error
messages in the logs (see below). What do they mean?

Here is an exemplary log entry, which I now have tons of:
2013-08-12 11:58:34.270

> A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request,
>   causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used
>   for the next request to your application. (Error code 121)

**Does anyone know what's causing error code 121? Is there some form of documentation? Is something wrong with my app? Is there a way to nudge the AppEngine team to have a look into this issue?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Java may be having some trouble today:  [AppEngine status](https://code.google.com/status/appengine)

Google does have a place where you can and should [Report Production Issues](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue)  Keep in mind that while Google reads those, they do not respond individually.

Refer to [Where to file AppEngine Issues](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3) for the full list of where to report the following:

- Billing Issues
- Defects
- Feature Requests
- Production Issues

Also, you should [file for SLA credit](https://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?contact_type=cloud_platform_billing)  (I mean I assume having to provide you credit would push them towards resolving the issue right!) if you are seeing:

- HTTP Request: INTERNAL_SERVING_ERROR
- Datastore api: INTERNAL_ERROR, TIMEOUT, BIGTABLE_ERROR,
  COMMITTED_BUT_STILL_APPLYING, TRY_ALTERNATE_BACKEND

Refer to [What Information do I Need to Qualify for SLA Credit](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#info_for_credit)

Comment: "It seems Java may be having some trouble today" Can you say what you saw? Everything is green on the AppEngine status page for me.

Comment: @Danack At the time I wrote it, there was a ? (investigating) mark under Java in the today column due to a spike in Latency  August 12, 2013 and an increased error rate for large gets.  I don't know if the time matches up to your issue though so those things may be unrelated...

Comment: Not my issue - but there does seem to be a tendency with cloud service providers to have an issue, fix it, and then mark that day as totally fine.